# expression meaning - brash talk does not always mean a pink slip

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does this expression mean? brash talk does not always mean a pink slip

Comment: litcrit if you ask.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary interpretation.
  

Answer (score 2):

> Speaking your mind to the boss will not always get you fired

Brash talk: self-assertive in a rude, noisy, or overbearing way.

Pink slip is a [discharge notice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_slip_%28employment%29)

I guess you got it from [here](http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20131018-you-said-what-to-the-boss)

> Revealing your true feelings about your boss or the work at hand can cost you respect, a promotion, or even your job.